# Dynamically register hystrix commands without javanica annotations in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, hystrix

We have developed a software proxy based on spring boot and zuul, that is meant to govern services within our integration layer. We do not own the systems consuming the various services, nor do we own the actual services themselves. The services are SOAP based webservices at present. We make use of pre, post , error and route filters. Validations are database driven, including which client is allowed to call what webservice. All service definitions reside in the database (request endpoint, request xsd, response xsd, which clients are allowed to invoke, etc.).

The aim now is to add hystrix commands to handle service failures, as well as a hystrix dashboard.

The standard way to use hystrix commands involves annotating service methods with javanica. Is there a way to dynamically declare/register hystrix commands for these webservices at runtime after reading the configurations from the database? The hystrix interception will need to happen based on the multiple webservice endpoints being invoked from a single point.

Hoping this is achievable ...if not, I would really appreciate any alternative proposals for how hystrix commands could be declared in this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you are already using Spring Boot and Zuul. How are you mapping the routes? Through the `url` param? Then you'll have to enroll your own. But if you define the routes as ribbon services and pass the routes as ribbon servers as described in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_using_ribbon_with_eureka) you will get Hystrix for free.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Apologies for the late response. No, we are not using the 'url' param. We are using a **route** Zuul filter and setting the url using 'requestContext.setRouteHost(new URL(serviceEndpoint));' where serviceEndpoint is setup as a property in an application.yml. I could try your suggestion of configuring ribbon services to get Hystrix configured automatically, but not sure how I would configure Hystrix properties per unique webservice that gets invoked. I might want to define fallback responses per webservice as an example. The software proxy has a list of services defined in the DB